# How to get notified in webview when a particular id is loaded

Tags: javascript, android

One table is getting loaded after clicking on one link in the same html file.
Is the any callback function which will get called after the table is loaded ?
When I am calling 
`document.getElementById('12245-SL-GN-0').click()`
 I am getting following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property click` of null
 because table was not loaded at that time.

Comment: How are you loading the table, is this coming from an Ajax call or is it being created in Javascript or somehow else?

Comment: It is created in java script

Comment: What about creating a small image with an onLoad() event in the last cell of the table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support  NickC I solved It by waiting until table was loaded in the script